# $P(T ≤ 5 | T ≥ 2)$ from CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If for discrete random variable T the CDF is defined as

$$F(t) = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{t<1}\\
1/4,  & \text{1≤t<3}\\
1/2,  & \text{3≤t<5}\\
3/4,  & \text{5≤t<7}\\
1, & \text{t≥7}
\end{cases}$$

How to find $P(T ≤ 5 | T ≥ 2)$

Comment: You can get proper spacing by using `\mid` instead of `|`.

Comment: Some hints: $P(T\leq 2)=\frac14 \Rightarrow P(T>2)=1-\frac14=\frac34$

$P(T\leq 5|T\geq 2)=\large{\frac{P(T\leq 5 \cap T\geq 2)}{P(T\geq 2)}=\frac{P(2\leq T \leq 5)}{P(T\geq 2)}}$____

$P(2\leq T \leq 5)=\frac12-\frac14=\frac14$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the definition of conditional probability,
$$P(T \leq 5 \mid T \geq 2) = \frac{P(2 \leq T \leq 5)}{P(T \geq 2)}.$$

After observing the CDF, it seems reasonable to see that the pdf is

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{4}&x \in [7],x \text{ is odd.} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{array}\right. .$$

Thus,

$$\frac{P(2 \leq T \leq 5)}{P(T \geq 2)} = \frac{P(T = 3) + P(T = 5)}{P(T = 3) + P(T = 5) + P(T = 7)}$$
$$= \frac{\frac{2}{4}}{\frac{3}{4}} = \frac{2}{3}$$

$$\implies P(T  \leq 5 \mid T \geq 2) = \frac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: You can get proper spacing by using `\mid` instead of `|`.

Comment: Why do you think that the random variable is discrete ?

Comment: @callculus Because the cumulative distribution function only increases at step discontinuities.